# Has the theory of fractional quantum mechanics been experimentally validated in any way?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, mathematics, stochastic-processes

I'm referring to the generalisation of quantum mechanics developed by Nick Laskin: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0206098

He suggests that if a particle's trajectory is integrated over Lévy paths then the fractional Schrodinger equation with fractional derivatives predicts its behaviour. So this leads me to the following question:

Is there any experimental evidence that the solutions to the fractional Schrodinger equation describe the behaviour of quantum systems?

Comment: More on [fractional derivatives](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22fractional+derivatives%22).

Comment: You should understand that today the academic is paper-driven, not problem-driven.